# What does the "lowest order adiabatic approximation" mean?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, density-functional-theory

I came across a concept "lowest order adiabatic approximation" in solid-state physics. I searched and found dozens of "lowest order adiabatic approximation". I think the "lowest order adiabatic approximation" is just the common "adiabatic approximation", i.e., the motion of the lattice does not induce transitions of electronic states. Beyond this "lowest order", the motion of the lattice would lead to transitions of electronic states. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “common” adiabatic approximation schemes include higher-order corrections, because they usually contain very interesting physics (e. g. Berry phases). What you call “common adiabatic approximation” is just the lowest/leading order adiabatic approximation.

*Beyond this "lowest order", the motion of the lattice would lead to transitions of electronic states. Am I right?*

No, you are not right. Adiabaticity avoids electronic transitions if there is a spectral gap present. However, you do get additional correction terms such as Berry phases that account for the back reaction of the fast electron dynamics onto the dynamics of the nuclei.

Comment: In solid state physics, the adiabatic approximation or the Born-Oppenheimer approximation means setting the terms "coupling of different electronic states by nuclei dynamics" zero. Since these terms are just the electron-phonon coupling, so it seems that in the adiabatic approximation, there is no electron-phonon coupling.

Comment: This is what is meant by Born-Oppenheimer approximation in some entry-level text books, but this is not true if you look at the state-of-the-art in research. What you describe is only the leading order, and many interesting phenomena are due to the subleading order. (Keep in mind that many standard text books are extremely old and have been written before these advances were made.) If you are interested in that topic, I can give you more specific pointers to more modern literature.

Comment: Thanks, @Max Lein, please kindly send me some easy-to-follow literatures' link. I know a recent review "electron-phonon interactions from first principles"

Comment: And, what does "What you describe is only the leading order, and many interesting phenomena are due to the subleading order." mean? I guess you meant neglecting the terms "coupling of different electronic states by nuclei dynamics" is the leading error? And why we have electron-phonon coupling in the adiabatic approximation?

Comment: To leading order the electrons are slaved to the nucleons, i. e. they instantaneously readjust to the nucleons's positions and momenta. The higher-order corrections take the back-reaction into account, where you have a back-reaction of the electronic dynamics onto the nucleonic dynamics. You have this back reaction, because the adiabatic parameter $\varepsilon = \sqrt{\nicefrac{m_{\mathrm{e}}}{m_{\mathrm{nuc}}}$ (the square root of the ratio of electronic to nucleonic mass) is not zero, but just small.

Comment: The leading-order corresponds to the $O(\varepsilon^0)$ term, but you can expand order-by-order in $\varepsilon$. The first back reaction is $O(\varepsilon)$. A pedagogical introduction to the topic is e. g. [this paper by Gianluca Panati, Herbert Spohn and Stefan Teufel](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.638.2900&rep=rep1&type=pdf). I would also recommend the works by George Hagedorn that are cited in there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation and articles. Really helpful!

Comment: Could you please help me look at Eq. (2.3) in this paper (https://journals.aps.org/prb/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevB.27.6083). I think the summation term of Eq. (2.3) is non-adiabatic. Am I right?

Comment: No, you are not, transport is fully adiabatic. What you see here are the first two terms in the adiabatic perturbation expansion in the small parameter (denoted with $\hbar$ in the paper, although that is not a good small parameter as it has units).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am confused because in this paper https://journals.aps.org/prb/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevB.50.11902 and right below Eq. (2.3), they have the words "at any following moment $t>0$,to the first order in the nonadiabatic correction."

Comment: I think the second term (the summation term) of Eq. (2.3) denotes non-adiabatic transitions to other states. Sorry, I am really confused.

Comment: No, there is no transitions, the Berry curvature is computed from a single band only. Regarding the language, there is a bit of non-uniformity here. The paper you quote is quite old and precedes the more modern works I have cited, which compute higher-order terms. Nowadays amongst experts adiabaticity means absence of transitions to unoccupied states due to a separation of (spatial or time) scales. In that sense, all the terms in equation (2.3) are adiabatic, the term involving the Berry curvature is simply a higher-order correction since it only involves the occupied energy band.